# how to enable/disable all the controls in a row of listview. while clicking checkbox inside the listview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listviewitem

I have a list view and its contain n number of check box. I want to do enable/disable when clicking the  first checkbox. 
i have written a code in jquery. But its taking all the check box in the page. I need to enable / disable only the selected row.

```
function EnableCurrentRowControls(chkID) 
{
        var chkBox = document.getElementById(chkID);
        var chkIDList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i = 0; i < chkIDList.length; i++) 
        {
            if (chkIDList[i].type == "checkbox" && chkIDList[i].id != chkBox.id) {

                 if (chkIDList[i].type == "checkbox" && chkIDList[i].id != chkBox.id) 
                   {
                        chkIDList[i].enabled = false;
                   }
            }
        }
}
```

Calling function in ListView Control

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkUserBoardMaping" OnClick="javascript:EnableCurrentRowControls(this.id)"
                                                            runat="server" />
```

Pls have a look and advice me..

Comment: Please add a row of your rendered HTML. So we could see how to traverse

Answer (score 1):

May be trying with something like this:

```
function EnableCurrentRowControls(element) {
        if ($(element).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox][id*=chkUserBoardMaping]').is(':checked')) {

            $(element).closest('tr').find('input[type=text][id*=myTextBox]').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else {
             $(element).closest('tr').find('input[type=text][id*=myTextBox]').prop("disabled");

        }
    }
```

You'll also have to change this 
(1. pass only this as an argument
2. change onclick event to onchange) :

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkUserBoardMaping" onchange="javascript:EnableCurrentRowControls(this)"
                                                        runat="server" />
```

Be sure that you changed control (myTextBox) name!